# Нужно ли останавливать Thread

Tags: android, многопоточность

Нужно ли останавливать Thread  когда activity уходит в onPause() или он остановиться сам ?

Comment: Не остановиться, вызывайте interrupt() и учите что это только флаг для остановки. p.s. если вы не ui thread имеете ввиду