# Как остановить Thread

Tags: многопоточность

Как остановить Thread когда программа находиться в protected void onPause() ?

```
Thread loadAd=new Thread(){

        @Override
        public void run(){

            while(!isInterrupted()){

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);  //1000ms = 1 sec

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,("OK"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };


    loadAd.start();
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нужно ли останавливать Thread](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/888958/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-thread)

Comment: Укажите язык программирования в метках.